# Combining `$` and `.` operators

Tags: haskell

The following code ([ideone](http://ideone.com/8OLAhe)) is an attempt to create an operator that is basically both a `.` and a `$` operator, depending on whether it is applied to a function or a value.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class SuperDot a b where
  type Result a b 
  ($.) :: a -> b -> Result a b

instance SuperDot (a -> b) a where
  type Result (a -> b) a = b
  ($.) f x = f x

instance SuperDot (b -> c) (a -> b) where
  type Result (b -> c) (a -> b) = (a -> c)
  ($.) f g = f . g

h1 :: Int -> Int
h1 x = x * 2

h2 :: Int -> Int
h2 x = x + 3

main = print (h2 $. h1 $. (5 :: Int))
```

It works, but only if I give everything explicit type signatures. Is there another way of doing this that still allows type inference?

Comment: I hate to say this, but why would you want to do this? Composing and applying functions aren't the same operations in any sense.

Comment: They're similar, in that they're all part of a family of functions with type: `(b -> c) -> (a1 -> ... -> an -> b) -> (a1 -> ... -> an -> c)`, for `n >= 0`. The function `>>=` does wildly different things depending on the monad.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid all type signatures, since eg, 5 can be an Int but also a function.  The compiler can't guess which one you meant.

Comment: How is `5` a function? `const 5` is a function, but I don't see how `5` is?

Comment: @Clinton: Integer literals are overloaded, so `5 :: Num a => a` can be a function if there is a `Num` instance for functions.

Comment: functions are values. That's kind of the point. Distinguishing between the two doesn't make any sense in a functional language.

Comment: In the presence of polymorphism you are going to have trouble distinguishing whether `f $. g` *means* application to pass `g` function as a value to `f`, or composition of `f` and `g`. (Not even talking about compiler understanding this; just tell the programmer what you mean first)

Answer (score 4):

No, since numeric literals are really `Num a => a` you have to provide some explicit hint that you do in fact want it to be an `Int`.

However, there is a slightly nicer way of doing this that we can steal from [`class-prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-0.8.0/docs/ClassyPrelude.html). We can provide a series of identity functions with restricted types

```
 asInt :: Int -> Int
 asInt = id

 asInteger :: Integer -> Integer
 asInteger = id

 asIntFun :: (Int -> a) -> Int -> a
 asIntFun = id
```

so on and so forth and then just write

```
 main = print (h2 $. h1 $. asInt 5)
 main = asIntFun print $. h2 $. h1 $. asInt 5
```

much prettier than a type annotation and can be passed around as a parameter and such.